# Python throws TypeError on issubclass() when issubclass() is never called

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I have a piece of code that runs perfectly most of the time, but every once in awhile I get this error in the traceback:

```
File "/path/to/somefile.py", line 272, in somefile
    sm = -0.5 * (wv[0]**2. / sm2 + numpy.log(2. * numpy.pi * sm2))
TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

I know what `issubclass()` does and understand the error, but I never called it; that line in the code is pure arithmetic, so I don't know why this `TypeError` is raised in the first place. My only theory is that Numpy is calling it behind the scenes, but then the traceback should show the problematic line in the Numpy source, right? What's going on?

**Updates:**

`wv` is an array of floats and `sm2` is a float scalar. The error is actually thrown by `numpy.log`, i.e. the (new) line

```
tmp = numpy.log(2. * numpy.pi * sm2)
```

No more information is provided in the error message, though.

**More updates:**

My current version of Numpy (from a Python prompt):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.2'
```

I changed the problem line to

```
try:
    tmp = numpy.log(2. * numpy.pi * sm2)
except TypeError:
    print type(sm2), 2. * numpy.pi * sm2
```

and got the output

```
<type 'numpy.float64'> 0.0
```

So it makes sense that there would be *some kind* of error, but if I do this (at a Python prompt)

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.log(0.)
```

I get the error I would expect (and am already handling in the code in question, via the `warning` module):

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
-inf
```

Comment: You don't say what each var is, but you can break this statement into small pieces to see where the error happens (probably on `numpy.log`)

Comment: @JBernardo is right—but you're almost certainly going to need to know (and tell us) what `sm2` (and possibly `wv`) is in order to solve this problem. So please, do both of his suggestions, not just the second one. (If you don't know what type they are, just print them out right before this line.)

Comment: @JBernardo and @abarnert, I've updated with the types of the variables and split the line so that `numpy.log` is executed first, then added on the next line; the error is actually thrown by `numpy.log` but the last traceback line is still in my code, not Numpy's.

Comment: If `issubclass()` is being called from C code, the traceback won't reflect that. I'd try catching that exception, and when it happens, see what `2. * numpy.pi * sm2` is. If that's not fruitful, I guess you are digging in the numpy source.

Comment: @PhilFrost, the value of `sm2` is 0. That explains why there should be some kind of error, but I would have expected a `RuntimeWarning` (see my updates above), and I'm already handling that.

Comment: @seberg, my Numpy version is 1.6.2 and `type(sm2)` gives me `<type 'numpy.float64'>`.

Comment: thanks, puzzling... I guess you did not actually mess with the warning settings (ie. change when a warning or an error is raised, or promote some warnings to errors)? This is certainly a bug, but without more information it seems unfortunately hard to figure out what is going on. (but if you have a small script you can upload, that would be great for a bug report!)

Comment: @seberg All I've done to mess with warning settings is `warnings.simplefilter("error", "RuntimeWarning")`, just so I can catch `RuntimeWarning` when it occurs and handle it intelligently. I'll try the code without it.

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars, thanks! Thats exactly the necessary information. With that `np.log(0)` fails. I would expect the warning is not done quite correctly in the C-Code... its easy to miss these things and very few ever change the warnings so its not noticed.

Comment: @seberg, I can confirm that, too, in a test script. Any thoughts on how I could still handle a `RuntimeWarning`? The code is an MCMC, so anything that results in an invalid calculation is supposed to be thrown out (given a `-inf` likelihood). Also, is there any point in reporting this as a bug, since it's so obscure?

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars, please do report it as a bug, there is no point in *not* reporting it, at the worst it will sit there for months... numpy already gives `-inf` for `0` and `nan` for negative numbers in `np.log`, so you can just work with those?

Comment: I'll report it. Also, I just found [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html), which I never thought to look for before. It seems that Numpy has a way of handling `RuntimeWarning` internally, so I'll see if I can use that instead. Thanks for all your help in solving this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an error in my code after all... As @seberg points out, this code works normally:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import warnings
>>> numpy.log(0.)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
-inf
>>> warnings.simplefilter("error", RuntimeWarning)    # not "RuntimeWarning"
>>> try:
...     numpy.log(0.)
... except RuntimeWarning:
...     print "caught"
...
caught
```

[`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy-seterr) provides an alternative to handling `RuntimeWarning` this way, though:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.seterr(all='raise')
{'over': 'warn', 'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}
>>> try:
...     numpy.log(0.)
... except FloatingPointError:
...     print "caught"
... 
caught
```

Either way, it works, though Python *really* should throw some kind of exception for passing a string instead of a class to `warnings.simplefilter`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault... just edit your answer, but it has to be `warnings.simplefilter("error", RuntimeWarning)` of course. If anything python could complain earlier before the actual event...

Comment: `warnings.simplefilter` may not raise an exception because [strings are valid exceptions](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-exceptions-came-to-be-classes.html) at least until Python 2.6. Maybe you are using an older version, or the warnings module didn't get the memo.

Comment: @PhilFrost, this is Python 2.7.3, so I guess it has to be `warnings`.